# Amasty promotions not working in Magento module

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have a cashier module that replaces the ordinary checkout i Magento 1.8. It has a unique url, such as **mystore.com/mycashier**

My problem is that the discount breakdowns (labels and individual discount amounts) in Amasty is not showing up in the cart. This is working in for example **mystore.com/checkout/cart** or **mystore.com/checkout/onepage**, but not in **mystore.com/mycashier**.

I found these specific lines in **discount.phtml**:

```
<?php if (is_array($this->getTotal()->getFullInfo())) : ?>
<?php foreach ($this->getTotal()->getFullInfo() as $info): ?>
```

**$this->getTotal()->getFullInfo()** is NULL in **mystore.com/mycashier**. So I tried to track down with profiler what was going on:

The following lines are found in the profiler when visiting **mystore.com/checkout/cart** but not when visiting **mystore.com/mycashier**:

```
OBSERVER: amasty_promo_model_observer   
CORE::create_object_of::Amasty_Rules_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine
CORE::create_object_of::Amasty_Rules_Model_SalesRule_Rule_Condition_Product
OBSERVER: amasty_rules_model_observer
```

However, notice that the total discount amount is visible and working perfectly, just not the individual discount labels and amounts.

What can I do to make this work and how do i do it?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? How can I get the observer to be launched on the 3rd party cashier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, thanks to Amasty.

In the cashier module I needed to trigger the salesrule_validator_process through **getTotals()**, specifically from **Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()**

So I added two lines before the layout rendering in the indexController file for the module:

```
    $new_quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $new_quote->collectTotals();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [promo module](http://amasty.com/special-promotions.html) in the question adds individual item discount in the file app\code\local\Amasty\Rules\Model\Observer.php

It observes event `salesrule_validator_process` and check if the item discount is greater than zero.  Then calls

```
$this->_addFullDescription($observer->getEvent()->getAddress(), 
                $rule, $item, $amountToDisplay);
```

The function, it it's turn sets the address full description.

Then it adds it in the class Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount and shows in the template.

So you custom module can
  1. do not throw the event
  2. rewrites the class Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount
  3. uses custom template for totals
  4. uses CSS that hides the discount (check page HTML source)

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. 

I'm pretty sure it is number 1: Do not throw the event.

2. No rewrites for this class in the module. I can not see Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount anywhere in the module code.
3. No custom templates for totals (it uses the default totals.phtml)
4. The data simply isn't in the HTML file at all.

Question: Would you mind telling me how to throw the event in the module?

Comment: I ran the profiler for the mystore.com/checkout/cart where the Amasty module details for the discount works perfectly and compared with mystore.com/newcheckoutmodule. This one is found in the checkout/cart DISPATCH EVENT:salesrule_validator_process 0.0278 1 207,472 262,144 but it is not found in the newcheckoutmodule. So the solution must be to launch the event for the newcheckoutmodule. Please give me some feedback on how to do it correctly, I would appreciate it a lot! Many thanks from a satisfied customer! :)

Comment: I think it depends on the checkout module, depending on it's logic you should throw the event in the right place.